# Lookup column to Page library with versioning remains empty after search crawl

Tags: search, lookup-column, versioning

We have a content type (named: Tiles) of 7 lookup site columns that point to the ID field of the Pages library on the same site. The Pages library has versioning (Create major and minor (draft) versions)  enabled.  We serve up the details of the "Tiles" via search results.  We've noticed that if we create a "Tile" that links to an unpublished page the value of the lookup field's managed property is empty in Search.  Via a CAML query I can see the lookup field has a value.  In order to populate the managed property in Search we need to publish the page AND update the "Tile" item, then perform a new crawl.

Is this expected?  Is there a way to use a lookup site column to store unpublished IDs?  When does the lookup column "check" the Page's status to store the value for a search crawl?

This one has been driving me crazy.  Any help is appreciated.